# Problem in interacting with Smart Contract using Web3.js (sendSignedTransaction)

Tags: solidity, web3js, typescript, sendsignedtransaction, cron-jobs

I am making a "CRON JOB" that can interact with my smart contract and call its function at a given interval. But I'm facing problem in interacting with my smart contract. I'm using Web3.js and my code is in **.ts**.

Github repo: https://github.com/APrakash-913/CRON-JOB_Smart_Contracts_TESTING

My main script is in **index.ts** in **src** folder.

Error I'm facing:

```
  return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
           ^
TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
    at /home/amaterasu/cron/node-cron-job/node_modules/web3-eth/src/utils/get_transaction_error.ts:62:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/amaterasu/cron/node-cron-job/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:24:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/amaterasu/cron/node-cron-job/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:20:12)
    at getTransactionError (/home/amaterasu/cron/node-cron-job/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amaterasu/cron/node-cron-job/node_modules/web3-eth/src/rpc_method_wrappers.ts:738:48)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/amaterasu/cron/node-cron-job/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:21:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  innerError: undefined,
  reason: 'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x9172BDC8973f91430ff81C49D05bd5416F4AB58a have 6483464549940618898 want 32705710217586123749359847200000000 (supplied gas 550000000)',
  signature: undefined,
  receipt: undefined,
  data: undefined,
  code: 402
```

From what I can deduce from the error, it is asking for way too much ETH (32705710217586123.749359847200000000) and my wallet has (around 6.5 ETH). Though my smart contract is very simple, I don't think it should ask that much ETH as gas for running a function.

My contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract Counter {
    uint256 private counter;

    constructor(uint256 _counter) {
        counter = _counter;
    }

    function incrementCounter() public {
        counter += 1;
    }

    function getCounter() public view returns (uint256) {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

I even tested my contract in Remix, it is not asking for that many ETH.

I tried to pinpoint the code which is causing the problem using **console.log(.....)**
⚠️in index.ts (according to me)

```typescript
// Broadcast Txn
      const signatureHash = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signedTransactionData
      );
      console.log("4-------------");
      console.log(signatureHash);
```

I'm stuck with this for over a week. Can anyone please help me??